# ORA-01424 with IntelliJ IDEA on Mac

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans, intellij-idea, exception

```
OS X 10.10.2
IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3
Oracle 11.2.0.1(installed on a Windows 8 virtual machine)

SYS.*
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character

  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1207)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDatabaseMetaData.getColumnsWithWildcards(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:348)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDatabaseMetaData.getColumns(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:125)
  in RemoteDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getColumns(RemoteDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:170)
  in RemoteUtil.access$100(RemoteUtil.java:36)
  in RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:227)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy137.getColumns(Unknown Source)
  in DatabaseSchemaLoader.loadTableBasicsInner(DatabaseSchemaLoader.java:1148)
```

I also connect database on NetBeans, but everything on NetBeans is OK.

This exception is thrown when refreshing database.

Yesterday it works very perfectly.

What can I do.

Comment: I had the same problem and could finally fix enabling "Use legacy introspector".